# removing leading zeros from delphi string

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Delphi 7

How do i remove leading zeros in a delphi string?

Example:

00000004357816

```
function removeLeadingZeros(ValueStr: String): String
begin
 result:= 
end;
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
function removeLeadingZeros(const Value: string): string;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 1 to Length(Value) do
    if Value[i]<>'0' then
    begin
      Result := Copy(Value, i, MaxInt);
      exit;
    end;
  Result := '';
end;
```

Depending on the exact requirements you may wish to trim whitespace. I have not done that here since it was not mentioned in the question.

**Update**

I fixed the bug that Serg identified in the original version of this answer.

Comment: what if there is a zero in the string (not necessary in the beginning? Example: 00000004307016

Comment: That's fine, the code just removes leading zeros as you requested. Your example will return '4307016' from this code.

Comment: @Shane, I think you should read the code once more.  It finds the first non-0 char and returns the rest of the string.

Comment: I read it, i didn't understand it. I made my comment then i tested it. It errored out a couple of times cause of missing semi-colons, and the addition of an extra "End"....but i figured it out and got it to compile and was able to test

Comment: Hmm...  ShowMessage(removeLeadingZeros('000'));

Comment: Wow David, you wrote it and didn't try it? :-)

Comment: @Warren yeah, silly me. I just thought I could write perfect code without testing it. Wrong again! Of course it would have been easy for @Serg to have fixed it with an edit to my post.  ;-)

Comment: I'm not sure `Copy(Value,i)` will compile with Delphi 7. Perhaps you should need to write `Copy(Value,i,maxInt)`

Answer (score 24):

Code that removes leading zeroes from '000'-like strings correctly:

```
function TrimLeadingZeros(const S: string): string;
var
  I, L: Integer;
begin
  L:= Length(S);
  I:= 1;
  while (I < L) and (S[I] = '0') do Inc(I);
  Result:= Copy(S, I);
end;
```

Comment: This is what I would have done. Much more efficient than David's answer.

Comment: Nice solution.  From a practicality standpoint, it will be more useful if the trim char ('0' in this case) is passed in as a parameter, then it can trim any char.

Comment: I am not sure if this is "much more efficient than David's answer", but it is slightly more elegant and, most importantly, doesn't show the bug in David's code.

Comment: +1 I wouldn't worry too much about efficiency. Getting it right is more important! For what it's worth there's no real difference in efficiency.

Comment: Calling this function for `0000.89` results in `.89` but `0.89` would be better.
So I think the line no. 7 could be changed to:
while (I < L) and (S[I] = '0') and (S[I+1] = '0') do Inc(I);

Answer (score 11):

Use [JEDI Code Library](http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/index.php?title=JEDI_Code_Library) to do this:

```
uses JclStrings;

var
  S: string;

begin
  S := StrTrimCharLeft('00000004357816', '0');
end.
```

Comment: You should probably mention (in case the OP doesn't know) that this requires the JEDI Code Library (JCL), and provide a link.

Answer (score 8):

Probably not the fastest one, but it's a one-liner ;-)

```
function RemoveLeadingZeros(const aValue: String): String;
begin
  Result := IntToStr(StrToIntDef(aValue,0));
end;
```

Only works for numbers within the Integer range, of course.

Comment: Also only if the string is actually a number. I.e. no alpha chars at all.

Answer (score 5):

Searching for this in 2021 there is a much better solution that I found now and that is using the TStringHelper function TrimLeft as follows

```
myString := myString.TrimLeft(['0']);
```

see here for more on the documentation http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.SysUtils.TStringHelper.TrimLeft

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as of 2021

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function TFrmMain.removeLeadingZeros(const yyy: string): string;
var
  xxx : string;
begin
  xxx:=yyy;
   while LeftStr(xxx,1) = '0' do
    begin
      Delete(xxx,1,1);
    end;
    Result:=xxx;
end;
```